# optimize mysql select in wordpress DB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, select, optimization

**Some data first:**

1. wordpress instalation (~ 110k posts, ~20k tags, ~250 categories, latest version)
2. W3 Total cache included (disk caching: database, object, page, browser)
3. server is VPS (4 GB RAM / up to 8 GB Dynamic, 2 vCores, Ubuntu 64bit)
4. Running Apache2, php 5.3.10, mysql 5.5.37

**What is running on the server:**

1. a few very small domains (traffic and resources close to 0)
2. 5 cron jobs that import data to WP

> The problem: viewing a post takes around 10 s. Refreshing is in no time as the caching plugin does a good job, however if the post hasn't been visited before the time for viewing it is around 10-12 s.

After some tracing in order to find out what is going on wrong I found out that mysql query for each page is taking some 90 - 95 % of the total time (9-10 seconds for each page).

I have tried to figure out if there is something wrong with mysql configuration and modified the fallowing from default in my.cnf:

```
key_buffer_size         = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2G
innodb_log_file_size = 256M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_thread_concurrency = 16
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 20M
query_cache_limit       = 8M
query_cache_size        = 64M
max_allowed_packet      = 16M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 32
```

After restarting there has not been any improvement at all since I guess I am missing something. I have started tracing with newrelic and their system points out that there are wueries that take upt to 34 s to execute.

Here is an SQL query from newrelic's log:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  qmV?_posts.ID FROM qmV?_posts  INNER JOIN qmV?_postmeta ON ( qmV?_posts.ID = qmV?_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE ?=?  AND ( 
  MONTH( qmV?_posts.post_date ) = ?
) AND qmV?_posts.post_type = ? AND (qmV?_posts.post_status = ?) AND ( 
  qmV?_postmeta.meta_key = ?
) GROUP BY qmV?_posts.ID ORDER BY qmV?_postmeta.meta_value+? DESC LIMIT ?, ?
```

I have tried also to verify wether the tables are indexed correctly and it appears to be so as (obviously) WP is doing a great job in optimizing search across the DB.

In subsidiary a monitoring tools reports "MySQL CPU usage" to something around 95% to 105% while this query is running.

Question: is there anything else I can tweak on this server or I should have a look at some other options for hosting this application? If you propose the 2'nd option please argument your option.

**Update 1:**
ps aux | grep 'mysqld' returns:

mysql      522 13.5  1.0 1227664 85128 ?       Ssl   2014 3513:12 /usr/sbin/mysqld

Comment: If you found queries that take up time, log on to your MySQL terminal and check execution plan by placing `EXPLAIN` before `SELECT` and check what MySQL does. That's the only way to see what's going on. However, what's weird is that you have 2GB allocated to InnoDB yet it appears that MySQL is hitting the disk hard. Can you verify your tables are all InnoDB and that you don't have MyISAM somewhere? Also, verify that your buffer_pool is indeed 2GB by running `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_pool%;` from MySQL terminal.

Comment: All are InnoDB. Query SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer_pool%; returns  5242880.

Comment: That's 5mb. Check how much RAM is allocated to MySQL using `top` or `ps`.

Comment: See update please. I cannot however find where that setting is placed ... could it be somewhere else rather than my.cnf?

Comment: can you try `lsof -p 522 | grep cnf` and check what it says about loaded config files. Your buffer pool is definitely not 2G, if it were - query would run faster.

Comment: returns nothing. I treid restarting the server and it appears to reinitiate correctly the variables however queryes are still painfully slow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68501/discussion-between-mugur-and-n-b).